# Preferred file extension for XSLT documents

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there a preferred file extension for [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) documents?

Both `.xsl` and `.xslt` are used frequently (where [.xsl is more popular](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=.xsl,.xslt)).

But is there any recommended / authoritative / best practice guideline for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XSLT 2.0 specification registered the MIME Media Type `application/xslt+xml` https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xslt-mime-definition, saying that 'XSLT documents are most often identified with the extensions ".xsl" or ".xslt"'. I would say it mostly depends on what works best for you and your environment and whether you can configure for instance your web server to make sure it associates the right MIME type with the suffix/file extension you use for your XSLT documents. But I think in practice `.xsl` with the MIME type `text/xsl` might still have the best interoperability.

Answer (score 0):

The mime type for xslt file is application/xslt\+xml. This worked for when i applied in my code.

Comment: This question is about the file extension, not the mime type